# When I present to a NavigationController "whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uinavigationcontroller, firebase-authentication

This is my Main `UITabBarController`. It's launching if there is an user, if there is not an user it presents to `SignAndLoginVC()`.

If there is an user an my `HomeVC()` launches there is no hierarchy problem but when logout then login again and after logout it says

> 2017-06-22 14:26:06.880 Seyahapp[16950:1337223] Warning: Attempt to
>   present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

```
    let logoutButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Logout", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(logout), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()
func logout(){

    do {
        try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
       }
    }catch let signOutErr as NSError{
        print("Couldnt sign out", signOutErr)

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.delegate = self
    FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
        if user == nil {
            let SALcontroller = SignAndLoginVC()
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SALcontroller)
            self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    })

    fetchUser()

    setUpControllers()
}
```

And this is what I do in `Signandloginvc()`

```
    func loginHandle() {
    let loginVC = LoginVC()

    UIButton.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 15, green: 193, blue: 131)
    }
    navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser == nil {
            print("there is no user")
    }
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 41, green: 80, blue: 80)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true

    logoSetup()
    buttonsSetup()

    }
```

if user clicks to the login button it pushes `LoginVC()`.
`SignandLoginVC()` , `LoginVC()`, `SignupVC()` those 3 vc's are navigation controller and `homeVC` is tabbar controller.

edit: What I do inside FIRAuth, for example print("123"). It does twice. I mean it prints 
123
123 
I couldnt understand.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to present modal view controller from embedded( vc on `UINavigationController` or `UITabbarController`) view controller. Depending on where your VC is embedded, present new modal VC from navigation or tabbar controller like `self.tabbarController.present(...)` or `self.navigationController.present(...)`. Hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

that's because these 2 lines of code:

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SALcontroller)
self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

you create a **UINavigationController**, and it caused the **hierarchy** problem.

Comment: But I have to create a  UINavigationController.

Comment: instead of there lines of code, use ```navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)```, check if it  solves the problem or not

Comment: Well the main reason is that Firebase's addStateDidChangeListener method calls inside twice and that is an interesting problem. So I decided to use if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser == nil instead of addStateDidChangeListener and my problem has solved.